# How to implement MVP when I use the same API call in two seperate presenters

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, mvp

I am using the same API call (i.e. getUserList) with retrofit for two different activities on Android in kotlin. Each activity has it's own presenter that takes care of that call, which is the way to do with MVP pattern, but the code is the same in both cases. This way there are two presenters with the same method that do the same thing. How can I organize it, that there would be only one implementation of the method that both presenters use while still implementing MVP pattern?

Comment: create a base presenter class which handles the api and extend that class in both activities presenter

Comment: create a singleton method on your application class